# How can I re-write this code in one line?

Tags: python

Is there a way to write if-else statement in a different way than this? Maybe shorter?

```
def __init__(self, attributes):
    self.attributes = attributes
    if "yes" in self.attributes:
        self.diabetes = "yes"
    elif "no" in self.attributes:
        self.diabetes = "no"
    else:
        self.diabetes = ""
```

Comment: Why must the code be in one line? Your just going to make it harder to read.

Comment: Doesn't really need to one line, but any other way than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
self.diabietes = 'yes' if 'yes' in attributes else 'no' if 'no' in attributes else ''
```

To improve it even further we need some assumptions about `attributes` type.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before and didn't work. Now I know where the mistake was! 
self.diabetes = "yes" if "yes" in self.attributes else self.diabetes = "no" if "no" in self.attributes else self.attributs = ""

Answer (score 0):

Two more ways:

```
self.diabetes = ('yes', 'no', '')[('yes' in attributes, 'no' in attributes, True).index(True)]
```

or

```
self.diabetes = [i for i in ('yes', 'no', '') if i in attributes][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def __init__(self, attributes):
    self.diabetes = ""
    if "yes" in attributes:self.diabetes = "yes"
    elif "no" in attributes:self.diabetes = "no"
```